# Adding an ACL rule from one user to others in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to pull an access rules from one user and apply it to all others. When I run the following it doesn't give an error but it also doesn't add the rule. When I log out $access it is the rule that I want (the fourth one in the list for that user). When I log out $acl it is the acl object for each user in the group. I don't get an error saying the method AddAccessRule doesn't exist.

When I look at the users in Active Directory after running the script there is no change made to them.

Does anyone know what I did wrong here or a better way to accomplish this?

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase “OU=Users,OU=Corporate Office,DC=corp,DC=company DC=com”-filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName 
$access = (Get-Acl ‘CN=peron,OU=Users,OU=Corporate Office,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com’).access[3]
    foreach ($user in $users){
        $acl = (Get-Acl $user)
       echo $acl
       $acl.AddAccessRule(($access))    
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code where you are applying the updated acl with `set-acl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978016/adding-an-acl-rule-from-one-user-to-others-in-powershell/44995268#comment76933426_44978016), you're not using `Set-ACL` at any point.

Adding an access rule and then not setting the updated ACL on the target object is comparable to modifying a word document and then not saving the changes.

```
foreach ($user in $users){
    $acl = (Get-Acl $user)
    $acl.AddAccessRule(($access))
    Set-Acl -AclObject $acl $user.DistinguishedName    
}
```